# Is it the internal modifier the reason why I cannot instantiate XmlElement?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I was trying to create an instance of `System.Xml.XmlElement`. I noticed, that its constructor signature was:

```
protected internal XmlElement(
    string prefix,
    string localName,
    string namespaceURI,
    XmlDocument doc
)
```

AFAIK the internal modifier makes the constructor be visible only within its assembly (System.Xml.dll). I was trying to instantiate it within my PowerShell script.

My code:

```
$doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$e = New-Object System.Xml.XmlElement -ArgumentList "foo","bar","baz",$doc
New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Xml.XmlElement.
At line:1 char:6
+ $e = New-Object System.Xml.XmlElement -ArgumentList "foo","bar","baz",$doc
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Also, I actually found no constructors at all:

```
([type]"System.Xml.XmlElement").GetConstructors()
```

(produced 0 lines of output)

What about the protected keyword? It is *also* preventing me from accessing the constructor, right?

Comment: You can't create an instance of `XmlElement`. `protected internal` means it is only available to derived classes within the same assembly.

Comment: got it. all clear. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** use the constructor because its *protected internal* (only for derived classes). However, just use the `CreateElement` method instead:

```
$doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$e = $doc.CreateElement("foo","bar","baz")
```